# OpenLDAP how to create and use an objectclass that is a child of inetOrgPerson

Tags: object, ldap, hierarchy, addressbook

I'm trying to create an LDAP based address book. For each recipient/user in it, I will need to store information about their contact points. Information will include:
contact type - phone/email/fax/pager/etc.
label - grandma's attic, work, home, etc.
address - actual phone number/email/etc.
and few other properties

I've figured out by now that there is nothing out of box that can handle this, but that I can create my own ContactPoint ObjectClass, make it a structural class and have it be a child of inetOrgPerson. but I still can't seem to wrap my head around how this all comes together. For example, how would I query for a person and his/her contact points?

Comment: ...any updates the last years?

Answer (score 3):

LDAP is designed to be extensible and defining new schema elements is often required. When clients cannot find an attribute with the syntax and name they desire, they should define a new attribute with an appropriate object class. Designers should:

- know the existing schema elements
- use existing schema elements where possible
- not use vendor-specific attributes, this results in poor quality, brittle systems. Use only attributes and object classes from schemas defined by the standards body (unless of course you roll your own)
- inherit from an existing object class instead of defining a new object class
- use matching rules (from the attribute type definition) for comparisons and not use language equality constructs.
- avoid the `extensibleObject` unless absolutely required. Using `extensibleObject` is a last resort option and is similar to using an untyped programming language and results in poor quality, brittle, difficult to maintain systems

For more information, please see ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)

Comment: Thanks Terry, this is very good general information, but how does it relate to what I asked?

Answer (score 1):

Make it an `inetOrgPerson` and an `extensibleObject`. Then you can use any attribute from anywhere in it. I would steer well clear of defining your own object classes.

Comment: thanks, but I couldn't find any object class that for example contains a contact label, or a contact type (as basic as it may seem). Also, I need to be able to associate one or more contact point objects with one person object. I don't see how you're proposing is going to achieve that.

Comment: @MorDeror `inetOrgPerson` already has attributes for `mail`, `telephoneNumber`, `homePhone`, `internationalISDNNumber`, `facsimileTelephoneNumber`, `pager`, `postalAddress`, `homePostalAddress`, etc etc etc. And there are plenty of other LDAP schema types in existence beyond `inetOrgPerson`. Of course if none of them does exactly what you want you will have to roll your own, as Terry suggests.

Comment: I know I have to "roll my own". My question was how to "roll" two levels of objects - i.e. a person (let's say some version of inetOrdPerson) and his/her contact points with their own properties.  Attributes that you mentioned don

Comment: @Mordechai Did you have any intention of finishing that last sentence?